# Does this proof of Godel's incompleteness theorem rely on soundness?

Tags: logic, incompleteness, provability

The proof of Godel's first incompleteness theorem is often paraphrased like this. First, find a sentence $\phi$ which is true exactly if it is not provable. If $\phi$ is false, it must be provable, meaning that it must be true. This is a contradiction. On the other hand, if it $\phi$ is provable, then it must be true, which means that is is not provable, also a contradiction.

In this version of the argument, it is assumed that any sentence that is provable is also true. This seems like some version of soundness. I know that Godel's proof assumes the consistency of the theory $T$ capable of doing arithmetic. Is soundness an additional assumption that must be made, or is it proven as a part of Godel's argument? I know that this is not soundness in the sense of a sound proof system, but maybe it's related? I am worried that the version of the proof I paraphrased also might be conflating provability in $T$, or $T\vdash \phi$ with the provability predicate holding for $\phi$, or $T\vdash \textrm{Pr}(\lceil \phi \rceil)$.

Thanks!

Edit: I learned that the kind of soundness I am referring to is called arithmetical soundness, which means that theorems proven by $T$ are true of the standard model of the natural numbers.

Comment: That's not a good reflection of how the proof works. The proof itself makes no soundness assumptions. It defines binary relation among numbers which, *in the metatheory*, corresponds to the fact that the first number is the number of a formal proof of the sentence whose number is the second number. Then it constructs a sentence $\phi$ that asserts that there is not number $m$ which is in the relation with the number $n$ we obtain through a series of well-defined operations. Then it verifies that the number number of $\phi$ is $n$. (cont)

Comment: (cont). It then argues: if the theory is consistent, then a proof of $\phi$ would establish that there is no number $m$ in the relation with $n$; and the proof itself would yield a number $m$ in the relation with $n$. This implies that there can be no proof of $\phi$. On the other hand, if there were a proof of $\neg\phi$, this would mean there is a number $m$ that is the number of a proof for $n$, and so you would be able to use $m$ to construct a proof of $\phi$, a contradiction. Thus, there can be no proof of $\neg\phi$. So either the theory is inconsistent, or incomplete.

Comment: Note that Goedel's Theorem is purely syntactic, not semantic. It is about *provability*, not about *truth*. That's why one should not introduce paraphrases that rely on "true" and "false"; the late Torkel Franzen wrote about this issue a lot, I recomment his writings.

Comment: I'm going to disagree, to a certain extent, with the existing comments/answers: **different proofs assume different things** (and there are [many proofs](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72062/what-are-some-proofs-of-godels-theorem-which-are-essentially-different-from-t) of the first incompleteness theorem). What is true is that we can prove a version of the incompleteness theorem without any soundness assumptions, namely "Any computably axiomatized consistent first-order theory interpreting $\mathsf{Q}$ is incomplete."

Comment: I recommend changing the title from "*the* proof" to "*this* proof" to emphasize that you're focusing on a specific argument, not the optimal situation.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin The argument you give that $\lnot \phi$ is not provable uses 1-soundness, not just consistency. In particular you jump from $\lnot \phi$ being provable to it being true (i.e. that there is in fact an $m$ that codes a proof for statement $n$). Stronger assumptions than consistency are unavoidable in this exact version of the proof, although one can replace 1-soundness with $\omega$-consistency to avoid explicitly semantic assumptions about the theory. Rosser's proof uses a different sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that the incompleteness theorem ultimately requires no extra hypotheses: Rosser improved Godel's original argument to show that (in modern phrasing) any consistent computably axiomatizable first-order theory interpreting $\mathsf{Q}$ is incomplete.

However, the specific argument you sketch in the OP

> find a sentence $\phi$ which is true exactly if it is not provable. If $\phi$ is false, it must be provable, meaning that it must be true. This is a contradiction. On the other hand, if it $\phi$ is provable, then it must be true, which means that is is not provable, also a contradiction.

(which can be made fully rigorous) **does** require soundness. Specifically, we can show that $T\not\vdash\phi$ without any soundness hypothesis (if $T\vdash\phi$ then $T\vdash \mathsf{Prov}_T\phi$ but we also have $T\vdash\phi\leftrightarrow\neg\mathsf{Prov}_T\phi$ so that would give a contradiction), but showing that $T\not\vdash\neg\phi$ requires $\Sigma_1$-soundness: think about a theory like $\mathsf{PA+\neg Con(PA)}$.

---

It's worth noting that there are other natural arguments which require even more soundness. For example, consider the following (I think due to Kotlarski?) which takes us to the two-quantifier level:

> Let $f(e)$ be $1+$ the value of the $e$th $T$-provably total recursive function on input $e$. Then $f$ is total recursive, but not $T$-provably total recursive. So "$f$ is total recursive" is a true sentence not provable in $T$.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that for that last argument $f(e)$ needs to be enumerating total recursive functions specifically in the order in which they are proven total by $T$?

Comment: @JamesHanson Essentially yes; there's some flexibility, but they more-or-less need to be enumerated in the order they "appear" in some appropriately-narrow sense in order for $f$ to be recursive.

Answer (score 1):

In order to prove that consistency alone suffices, Rosser needed to construct a [different sentence than Gödel's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser%27s_trick).

There's a nice proof from just the standard minimal assumptions (consistent, recursively axiomatizable, extends Robinson arithmetic), that doesn't use Rosser's trick, but uses a bit more computability theory and doesn't give an explicit undecidable sentence:

1. Assume for the sake of contradiction that $T$ is a complete, consistent, recursively axiomatizable theory extending Robinson arithmetic.
2. A recursively axiomatizable, complete and consistent theory is recursively decidable, since one can enumerate all possible proofs and wait for a proof of either $\phi$ or $\lnot\phi.$ Furthermore, any recursively decidable relation is representable in Robinson arithmetic and thus in $T$. Thus there is an arithmetical predicate $F(v)$ such that $T\vdash F(\mathbf n)$ if $n$ is the number of a sentence provable in $T$ and $T\vdash \lnot F(\mathbf n)$ if $n$ is the number of a sentence not provable in $T.$
3. Use the [diagonalization lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_lemma) to find a sentence $\varphi$ such that $T\vdash \varphi\leftrightarrow \lnot F(\ulcorner \varphi \urcorner).$ If $\varphi$ is provable in $T$ then so is $F(\ulcorner \varphi \urcorner)$ (by representation) and so is $\lnot F(\ulcorner \varphi \urcorner)$ (by equivalence), which is impossible since $T$ is consistent. On the other hand if, $\varphi$ is not provable, then $\lnot F(\ulcorner \varphi \urcorner)$ is provable (by representation), so $\varphi$ is provable (by equiavalence)... an outright contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Godel’s Incompleteness Theorem does not assume soundness or consistency, but states that there is no consistent, recursive, and complete theory of arithmetic. Or: *if* we have a consistent and recursive set of axioms, then they are not complete.

So why is it called just the Incompleteness Theorem? It’s because we *really* want consistency and recursiveness, but completeness is ‘merely nice to have’. So, in *some* sense you are right: once we do assume consistency and recursiveness, then incompleteness follows.